# how to fetch two models at the same time in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-class-based-views

i want to fetch two model in same html but unable to get both only getting one i am using class based view in django

here is my views.py

```
class home(View):
    def get(self, request,):
        category_list = Categories.objects.all()
        print(category_list)
        return render (request, 'home.html', {'category_list': category_list })

    def get (self, request):
        subcategory_list = Subcategories.objects.all()
        return render (request, 'home.html', {'subcategory_list': subcategory_list})
```

i guess i cannot call get function two time in cbv i have to make both of the model in same function help will be appreciated
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple values into context inside single `get()` function:

```
class home(View):
    def get(self, request,):
        category_list = Categories.objects.all()
        subcategory_list = Subcategories.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'category_list': category_list,'subcategory_list': subcategory_list})
```